# With Django Rest Framework, how can I grab the sub-objects of a specific entity?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If I want to, say, grab all of the questions of survey 5, a “RESTful” url for that would look something like “http://domain.com/api/survey/5/question/“.

Does DRF provide something for that such that I wouldn’t have to override `get_queryset()` and *manually* grab the survey ID out of the URL and *manually* filter down the `Question` queryset?

It seems like something like that would be built in to DRF such that I wouldn’t need to re-invent the wheel each time I wanted to grab the sub objects of a *specific* object, but I'm not finding it so far...

I'm using DRF 3.

Comment: I don't believe that there is any way to do this automatically. My typical solution to this problem is to create a new detail route as a class method of the viewset, which works well enough. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker just pointed me to this: https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers, the existence of which hints that such functionality *isn't* (yet) built into DRF.

After testing around a little bit, and appears easy enough to use.